# Show contacts with multiple phone numbers using CursorLoader

Tags: android, android-contacts, android-cursoradapter, android-cursorloader

I want to retrieve all the contacts in an Android phone along with all their phone numbers. Let's say following is the list of contacts on my phone along with their phone numbers:

A - 1111 (Mobile), 2222(Home), 3333(Work)

B - 4444 (Mobile), 5555(Home)

C - 6666 (Mobile), 7777(Home), 8888(Work)

I want to display the contacts in the following fashion but using CursorLoader.

[image]

Things I have tried :

- Get all the contacts and their phone numbers at a time and save them in an array list of custom contact objects and use them to display the list in a RecyclerView.

  - Issue with this is that if there are a lot of phone numbers then re-visiting this screen causes a blank screen possibly either due to resource not being free or memory leak issues.

Stack Overflow won't indent the code properly so here it is: https://pastebin.com/y9i5R5iN

```
final Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, String.valueOf(contactListCursor.getLong(ContactsQuery.ID)));
                    Uri thisContactUri = ContactsContract.Contacts.lookupContact(context.getContentResolver(), uri);
                    final UserContact contact = new UserContact();
                    contact.setName(contactListCursor.getString(contactListCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME)));
                    final ArrayList<PhoneType> multipleContacts = new ArrayList<>();
                    final Uri phoneNumUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(thisContactUri, ContactsContract.Contacts.Data.CONTENT_DIRECTORY);
                    final Cursor contactPhoneNumCursor = contentResolver.query(phoneNumUri, ContactPhoneQuery.PROJECTION, ContactPhoneQuery.SELECTION, null, null);
```

- Get all the contacts using a CursorLoader and a CursorAdapter by querying the ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI and getting the ID and DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY. In the getView() method I thought I could initialize a second CursorLoader to call into the details of the contact that the first cursor has given me. Something like this :

IF the user has multiple contacts then show a list of radio buttons, else show a textview with the only number they have.

This seems to load the phone numbers in advance and not update the view later on. Either because there's a delay or something I am not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Found a way to do it. 
Used the CursorLoader to pass to the CustomAdapter for initial query of contacts and then used the _ID field to lookup the contact and created a URI for the contact and looked up the Phone specific details inside the CustomAdapter's getView method itself.

I was trying to use CursorLoaders in both or Bulk loads in both. The hybrid approach worked out best.

Hope this helps someone. :)

Comment: you should really really avoid doing cursor reads on getView, this will result in horrible performance for some devices, and a very bad scroll performance. I'll post a simpler solution tomorrow if I have the time

Comment: Yes I agree and I do see a performance issue while scrolling in some of the older phones but when you say I should avoid cursor reads in getView do you mean I should not do the second part where I lookup the _ID field and get all the phone numbers of the contact? OR Do you mean I shouldn't use the cursor loader at all with the CustomAdapter on a listview? Because the example on Android's developer page uses a cursor to load the contact name and a second cursor to get the details in onClick. I'd be glad if you could suggest a better way though, as that will smoothen the scroll on older devices.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a single query to get all phone numbers in the Database along with their contact-ids and contact-names.

I would run this single query once, store all data in a map (contact-id => name, phone, ...)
And then use a custom adapter to display the map as a list of contacts.

Here's the code for querying all phones along with contact-ids and names (make sure you import everything from `ContactsContract`):

```
Map<Long, List<String>> contacts = new HashMap<Long, List<String>>();

String[] projection = { Data.CONTACT_ID, Data.DISPLAY_NAME, Data.MIMETYPE, Data.DATA1, Data.DATA2, Data.DATA3 };
String selection = Data.MIMETYPE + " IN ('" + Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "')";
Cursor cur = cr.query(Data.CONTENT_URI, projection, selection, null, null);

while (cur != null && cur.moveToNext()) {
    long id = cur.getLong(0);
    String name = cur.getString(1);
    String mime = cur.getString(2); // type of data (e.g. "phone")
    String data = cur.getString(3); // the actual info, e.g. +1-212-555-1234
    int type = cur.getInt(4); // a numeric value representing type: e.g. home / office / personal
    String label = cur.getString(5); // a custom label in case type is "TYPE_CUSTOM"

    String labelStr = Phone.getTypeLabel(getResources(), type, label);
    Log.d(TAG, "got " + id + ", " + name + ", " + kind + " - " + data + " (" + labelStr + ")");

    // add info to existing list if this contact-id was already found, or create a new list in case it's new
    List<String> infos;
    if (contacts.containsKey(id)) {
        infos = contacts.get(id);
    } else {
        infos = new ArrayList<String>();
        infos.add("name = " + name);
        contacts.put(id, infos);
    }
    infos.add(kind + " = " + data + " (" + labelStr + ")");
}
```

Note: The map's value is a list of strings, just for code-clarity. You should change it to be a custom `Contact` object that holds the name and list of phones in a proper Java Object

Comment: I tried doing this earlier but when the phone has a lot of contacts in the range of 600-1000, then , 1) it freezes the contact resource. So switching into and back out of the contact list screen causes a blank screen. 2) It also makes the screen less responsive. 3) it may take up the heap space and in case it gets GC-ed then i'll have to call a reload on it when the screen is loading causing the issue#1.  Correct me if my understanding is wrong

Comment: sounds like you're trying to run the query on the main thread, you should display a loading animation on screen, and load the contacts map in an `AsyncTask`, you can pre-fetch the contacts list before the user enters the screen to reduce or even eliminate the loading time.